# cdn.sstatic.net - states it is a cookie-less domain

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering why the cloudflare cookie is being sent in every request to the CDN? Is this something you guys are aware of?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238833/why-does-sstatic-net-serve-cookies